# How could be memory dump saved in kubernetes cluster after crashing?

Tags: java, kubernetes, out-of-memory, kubernetes-pod, heap-dump

When JVM crashes with `OutOfMemoryError` there are some options to store a dump:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath=./java_pid<pid>.hprof
```

but what does it happen in kubernetes cluster after crashing? It seems kubernetes will clean up everything related to the pod crushed? How can I save it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just mount it as a volume.

```
volumeMounts:
        - name: heap-dumps
          mountPath: /dumps
      volumes:
      - name: heap-dumps
        emptyDir: {}
```

[How to do a java heap dump in K8s](https://danlebrero.com/2018/11/20/how-to-do-java-jvm-heapdump-in-kubernetes/)

Comment: so does it mean it should be done on every pod running java application/microservice?

Comment: WIll this volume persist the pod destruction and new one creation?

Comment: If the pod moves to a different node, the data is lost. So this is not a fool-proof solution unless you have only one node in your cluster.